# Connecting to samba share works with smbclient, but doesn't work with Windows 7

Tags: samba

I tried to share the directory `/home/me/music` with Samba. The output of `testparm` on my server is as follows (I think this is Ubuntu's default configuration, except for the `[share]` section):

```
[global]
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
map to guest = Bad User
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = Yes
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
dns proxy = No
usershare allow guests = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
create mask = 0700
printable = Yes
browseable = No

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[share]
comment = My music files
path = /home/me/music
create mask = 0755
```

I used `smbpasswd` to give a passwort to the user `friend`.

When I try to connect to the share from another Ubuntu machine with `smbclient`, everything seems fine:

```
smbclient -U friend //192.168.1.2/share
```

I can call `dir`, and I see the content of the directory.

However, when I want to connect the network drive from a Windows 7 machine (`\\192.168.1.2\share` with user `WORKGROUP\friend`), I get the error that the network address is not reachable (I cannot tell the exact error message, because I have a German Windows version). The error is misleading, because I can ping 192.168.1.2 from the Windows machine.

I guess I am not the first person to run into this, but Googling for "samba" and "network unreachable" doesn't help. I hope somebody can tell me what's wrong with my config, and what's the difference between running `smbclient` and connecting from Windows.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Netscan (for windows) is a very handy tool for browsing lan. There is a similar application for linux too, named ---ShareScanner (netscan for linux). You can download it from:

http://sharescanner.net84.net

The site contains 32 and 64 bit debian and rpm packages for easy installation. It is actually a gui for smbclient

Comment: *(Using third party software is always a users risk)*

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 uses SMB2 protocol.  If you are running Samba 3.5 or earlier, it supports SMB1 and may not be completely compatible.  SMB2 support was added to Samba in version 3.6 .  NOTE: The newest verson of MacOS "Mavericks" will support SMB2 also starting in Fall 2013.